# Hauppauge WinTV-dualHD not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, tv-tuner

I have followed instructions on http://www.hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html but it's not working anymore on 16.04 aswell as 18.04. Any help would be appreciated. It appears that the kernel (by brad love) isn't installing from this ppa https://launchpad.net/~b-rad/+archive/ubuntu/test-test-hw-staging. So I'm looking at installing the linux kernel 4.18.0-20201905291620.0+mediatree+hauppauge which should still work. I just don't know how to do it. Cheers for any help

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm bumping up against a similar issues.