# How do I open Hauppauge WinTV in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

How do I open Hauppauge WinTV in ubuntu 18.04?
This same question was asked with no answer by Chris Hutton on Nov. 22, 2019 at:
[Hauppauge WinTV-dualHD not working on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158544/hauppauge-wintv-dualhd-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)
So, I'm asking again.
Like Chris, I followed the Install WinTV on Ubuntu HWE version installation instructions from this page:
Source: https://hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html
Everything seemed to install without any errors.
When it was all finished there it sat and still sets since 3-18-2020.
I can't find a way to open WinTV.
I'm not all that familiar with the linux jargon so please keep it in layman's terms if someone does have an answer. I have followed all the links associated with this but cannot see an answer in any of them.
I have searched Activities but all it gives me are links to things I've saved on my computer about Hauppauge WinTV.
I just tried running the instructions from this page:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/hauppauge/linux/hdpvr2_linux_readme.txt
The first instruction is:

```
Extract hauppauge_hdpvr2_.tar.gz
```

For this guide the file was saved and extracted on Desktop.
But it does not tell you how to extract it?
So, I went ahead and ran these instructions thinking maybe these are the instructions they're talking about:

Install build-essential

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Move to hauppauge folder on Desktop

```
$ cd Desktop
$ cd hauppauge_hdpvr2_
```

Got: `bash: cd: hauppauge_hdpvr2_: No such file or directory`
So I created the directory:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Desktop$ mkdir hauppauge_hdpvr2_
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Desktop$ cd hauppauge_hdpvr2_
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Desktop/hauppauge_hdpvr2_$
```

and continued...

Copy file 99-Hauppauge-PVR2.rules

```
$ sudo cp 99-Hauppauge-PVR2.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

Got:

```
cp: cannot stat '99-Hauppauge-PVR2.rules': No such file or directory

rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Desktop$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I could see this was useless and Stopped.

Is there a driver I need? If so, how do I know what one?
This page shows a bunch of drivers but not what they are for?
https://hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html#hdpvr2

Thanks for any help you can provide,
Rob

Comment: Start with extracting the `.tar.gz` file as explained e.g. here: http://www.rebol.com/docs/unpack-tar-gz.html

Comment: Thanks for the link: